# How to customize the Semantic UI buttons(background-color, border-radius and all)

Tags: semantic-ui

How to customize the Semantic UI buttons(background-color, border-radius and all)

```
<button class="ui button create-new-menu-btn">Create New Menu</button>

. create-new-menu-btn {
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: red;
}
```

*The above code is not working*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make your custom properties more specific than the ones semantic is using. How specificity works (simply) is that when there are competing property values on the same element, the one that is more "specific" is chosen.

Read this to know more about CSS specificity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

For your particular problem:

One way to make your custom CSS more specific is to use an id in the body tag of your page and use the following selector:

**Method 1**

```
#bodyid .create-new-menu-btn {
    //Properties
}
```

Another way is to simply add an id to the element you want to select

**Method 2**

```
#create-new-menu-btn {
}
```

Method 1 is preferred when you want to apply the properties on multiple elements (hence the use of a class) (Like multiple comment buttons on a page)

Method 2 is preferred when there is a single element to be selected. (Like a login/signup button in the header)

Comment: Thanks! for the answer @Sarthak and I have a doubt. Using id is not recommended in CSS right? Is there is any other way of doing it without id selector?

Comment: @Naveen using a id in the body tag is the generally accepted way of overriding the CSS of frameworks like bootstrap and semantic-ui. Go with Method 1. Method 2 is not preferred when coding because of inability to follow the DRY principles.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add semantic ui's classes before your own for specificity. 
For example : if your **className** is `.create-new-menu-btn` you can add in css or scss before `ui.button` or any other semantic ui specific clas that you neeed. So in the end, your class definition in css would look like this:

```
ui.button.create-new-menu-btn {
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If using JSX, you can use inline styling for the targeted elements

Example:

```
<Button style={{backgroundColor: 'red', borderRadius: 0}}> View Created </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#bodyId .ui.create-new-menu-btn {
border-radius: 0;
background-color: red;
```

}

It will target all button with **ui** class.

Hope It will be useful :)

Comment: Thanks! for the answer @priya_singh and I have a doubt. Using id is not recommended in CSS right? Is there is any other way of doing it without id selector?

Comment: Yes. Just increase its specificity so that it overrides existing ui styling.

Answer (score 0):

Put `.ui.button` infront of your class name `create-new-btn`. It should look like below

```css
.ui.button.create-new-btn {
  //Your css code
}
```

Then in your html/jsx template you can use the class name `create-new-btn` like below:

```html
<Button class="create-new-btn"/>
or for Jsx
<Button className="create-new-btn"/>
```