# semantic !important modifier interfering with styling

Tags: css, semantic-ui

Is there any way to disable all these `!important` options in [semantic-ui](http://semantic-ui.com/)?

I keep running into issues with things like:

```
.ui.right.sidebar {
    right: 0!important;                       /* why is this important */
    left: auto!important;                     /* why is this important */
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0); /* why is this NOT important */
    transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);         /* why is this NOT important */
}
```

Why does almost every positioning property have `!important`? Is there a way to compile semantic omitting the `!important` modifiers? It is interfering with my custom styling, and I have to do extra work that feels hacky (like countering `margin: 0!important;` with `padding-top: NNpx` and just hope that at least one isn't marked as `!important` in any of the states it could be in)

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11178731/4256677) are some options

Comment: @varontron no-no-no i dont want to ADD to the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling `!important` in semantic-ui is a bad idea as it may lead to unpredictable results. To understand more about why there are `!important` keywords in the framework, here are some statements made by Jack Lukic, the author of SUI:

> ..CSS should have a specificity property for defining priority (it was
>   part of the original discussion when creating css), however they left
>   us with automatic weight calculations from an arbitrary point system.
>
> This is pretty terrible when you run into something that happens to be
>   classified less ".ui.button" lets say, having to override '.ui.menu
>   .ui.button' , there are only two solutions, arbitrarily increasing
>   weight by repeating class names in selectors, or using important...

[Source 1](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/3041)

And also [here](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/280) (among other places):

> ...CSS specificity has always been a terrible sort spot of the
>   standard, instead of giving developers a way to assign priority to
>   rules we have to with two options, increase rule specificity or 'drop
>   the hammer' with !important.
>
> A lot of css rules in semantic aren't able to increase specificity beyond a certain point. The only assumption we can make about a red ui
>   button is that it will have classes .ui.red.button, no greater
>   specificity can be gained by altering the selector. If we then have a
>   rule that appears later with the same or greater specificity we're
>   stuck without important.
>
> I'm positive that each decision to use important in semantic was after dealing with no other option. This happens a bit more than other
>   libraries because the specificity is so granular in the library.

If you want to override the behavior, you can do two things:

1. Use one of the [3000 theming CSS variable](http://semantic-ui.com/usage/theming.html)s in SUI

OR

2. Override the behavior by using more specific selectors
   See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39660133/5192503)

> One way to make your custom CSS more specific is to use an id in the
>   body tag of your page and use the following selector:

```
#bodyid .create-new-menu-btn {
     //Properties }
```